# Why was Kashyyyk a system the Republic could not afford to lose?

Tags: star-wars, revenge-of-the-sith

In *Star Wars Episode III: Revenge of the Sith* the Jedi Council famously decides to send Yoda to help defend against the droid attack on the Wookiees, under the grounds that it was a system they couldn't afford to lose. Why would Kashyyyk be so important? It is a planet covered in trees...and that's basically it. Was some resource abundant on that planet? Was it an important strategic position? Did the CIS want to use the Wookiees as slaves to advance their war effort?

Memes aside why on Coruscant should Ki Adi Mundi care about the droid attack on the Wookiees?

Comment: <insert howling sound>

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It was location, location, location. [Per the official Star Wars databank](https://www.starwars.com/databank/kashyyyk):

> A verdant world **occupying a strategic position in the Mid Rim**, Kashyyyk was the site of a fierce fight between the Republic and Separatist invaders in the final days of the Clone Wars. Jedi Masters Luminara Unduli and Yoda were among the commanders of a mixed force of clones and Wookiees that defended the coastal city of Kachirho.

Similarly but slightly different, the old Star Wars Encyclopedia [had this to say](https://web.archive.org/web/20140108014212/http://starwars.com/explore/encyclopedia/groups/wookiees/):

> Loyal to the Republic, Kashyyyk was of prime strategic importance,
>   **serving as a major navigational point for the entire southwestern
>   quadrant of the galaxy**.

Answer (score 1):

Kashyyyk has, according to the [*Star Wars: Battles that Changed the Galaxy*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Battles_that_Changed_the_Galaxy) factbook, a number of key strategic elements that make it worth capturing.

**Location:**

> The Republic’s 12th Sector Army took aim at the so-called Foundry of
> the Confederacy, whose factory worlds included Boz Pity, Metalorn,
> Saleucami, and Felucia. As the Outer Rim Sieges pushed Separatist
> economies to the brink of collapse, Count Dooku and General Grievous
> sought to reverse their fortunes by kidnapping Palpatine during a
> lightning raid on Coruscant. This desperate gambit failed: Dooku died
> and Grievous fled into the Outer Rim. But the war wasn’t over.
> **Kashyyyk occupied a strategic position in the Mid Rim, sitting on the
> doorstep of the Foundry at a junction of hyperspace routes.**

**Intel:**

> *Kashyyyk's location was enough to make the Wookiee homeworld
> an attractive target, but **the Separatists also sought the data
> vault maintained by the Claatuvac Guild in the ancient tree-city
> of Kachirho. The guild’s Wookiee scouts had blazed secret
> hyperspace routes across the galaxy.** Seizing those routes could
> prolong the war, something the Republic vowed to prevent.*